# Beginner FizzBuzz solution

Tags: javascript, beginner, fizzbuzz

Is this a bad solution to the FizzBuzz thing?

I decided to make it print "Fizz Buzz" for the numbers divisible by 3 and 5 just for practice/understanding.

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
var output = "";
if (n % 3 == 0)
    output += "fizz";

if (n % 5 == 0)
    output += "buzz";

if (n % 5 == 0 && n % 3 == 0)
    output = "fizz buzz";

console.log(output || n);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Indentation:

You're missing indentation in your code, you should space out each level of indentation.

For example:

> ```
> for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
> var output = "";
> if (n % 3 == 0)
>     output += "fizz";
> ```

would become:

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
    var output = "";
    if (n % 3 == 0)
        output += "fizz";
```

---

## Use braces

You should wrap your code in braces, so you don't cause any bugs unknowingly:

For example, you (or someone in future that maintains your code) might think this wouldn't log anything, however, `"omg"` is logged.

> ```
> if (5 != 5)
>     console.log("wow");
>     console.log("omg")
> ```

Even [Apple](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) got caught out by one of these bugs.

---

## Unnecessary logic:

In your block, you check whether the number is divisible by 3, then by 5, then by 3 and 5. You don't need to perform the last check of 3 and 5, the first two make up that one.

---

## Leaving you with:

Implementing all those changes, you would end up with:

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
    var output = "";
    if (n % 3 == 0){
        output += "fizz";
    }
    if (n % 5 == 0){
        output += "buzz";
    }
    console.log(output || n);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The only reason I added that last bit was to see if the code would still function. It also outputs "fizz buzz" instead of "fizzbuzz" for numbers divisible by both. Unnecessary, just there for my personal learning.